# How to first setup DNS on my 2k8 server to have ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com configured?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I'm running a site on my dedicated server with windows server 2008 , iis & dns has been installed without any configs, have one dedicated ip address.

when I type the dedicated ip of the server in a browser, I can see my website working OK.

I have a domain registered with a reseller and I'm attempting to have the domain resolve to my server (built-in localhost website).

How do I properly setup the ns1 & ns2 nameservers and web zones for that domain , so its publicly live and view able?

I have access to my registrar panel that enables me to change DNS of registered domain to ns1 and ns2.

summary : how to create these ns1 and ns2 in my server?

Comment: What do you mean by (built-in localhost website) ?

Comment: @Sandman4 : I mean my server IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Actually I should use host headers to see my website.
 simply I add a AAA record to my domain control panel (registrar panel) to point to my server valid IP address.

Then I add a binding to my website in IIS with mydomain.com in the domain field.

and its done!

Answer (score 1):

Normally ns1 and ns2 meant to be TWO separate servers. You need additional server, or maybe your registrar will let you go with just one server or alternatively will let you set ns1 and ns2 to the same IP. Anyway, you not supposed to do such "tricks".

Actually some, if not most registrars provide DNS servers as well, if so you need just go to their control panel and setup A record to point to your server IP. If your registrar does not,
you may signup to some 3-rd party DNS service (some are free, like zoneedit.com) and they will provide DNS for you.